# How to get json data in for loop for disply

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

php code:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tlb_comments(user_id,comments) values ('$vw_id','$name')");
$comments = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tlb_comments");
$avatar   = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tlb_avatar WHERE `vw_id`='".$vw_id."'");
$avatar_select  =  mysqli_fetch_all($avatar);
$comment_select =  mysqli_fetch_all($comments);
array_push($avatar_select,$comment_select);
echo json_encode($avatar_select);
```

Jquery Ajax:

```
$(".comment").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    var name = $("#username_" + id).val();
    if (name == '') {
        alert("Please Fill All Fields");
    } else {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "comments",
            data: {
                username: name
            },
            success: function(html) {

                $("#cmt_output").html(html);
                console.log(html);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Json Array:

```
[
   [
      "11",
      "6",
      "1509947417_User_Avatar_2.png"
   ],
   [
      [
         "113",
         "0",
         "6",
         "all of us",
         "0"
      ],
      [
         "114",
         "0",
         "6",
         "all of us",
         "0"
      ],
      [
         "115",
         "0",
         "6",
         "welcome....",
         "0"
      ]
   ]
]
```

Comment: try to add some description explaining exact problem

Comment: Now display to my front end json array data type. how to convert data type

Comment: Now display to my front end json array data type. how to convert data text type

Comment: you mean you want to convert json to javascript abject use [jQuery.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)

Comment: Hmmm , Okay I will Try It......

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to return the asssociative array from php so you can easily read the json array with key of each array element...